# Yet another "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to pull one field from a view in my database. I determined there is data for this one instance, I correctly set up the SQLDataReader (I believe), the debugger verifies that I have rows in the DataReader, yet when I try to read I get an error.

Here's the code:

```
    public string[] getReasons(string Accession) {
        string[] reasonList = new string[0];
        SqlParameter accNumber = new SqlParameter();
        accNumber.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        accNumber.ParameterName = "@Accession";
        accNumber.Value = Accession;
        string selectText = "select reason from pendingList where accession = @Accession";
        SqlCommand selectStmt = new SqlCommand(selectText,toPending);
        selectStmt.Parameters.Add(accNumber);

        if (selectStmt.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) {
            selectStmt.Connection.Open();
        }
        SqlDataReader pendList = selectStmt.ExecuteReader();

        while (pendList.Read()) {
            reasonList[reasonList.Length] = pendList["reason"].toString();
        }

        pendList.Close();

        return reasonList;
    }
```

I call getReasons('RAM4658980'). I've verified that the following SQL query

```
select reason 
from pendingList 
where accession = 'RAM4658980'
```

returns exactly one row. The `pendList` variable looks like this:

[image: pendList variable contents]

I'm not sure why I get "Enumeration yielded no results"; and at the `reasonList[reasonList.Length] = pendList["reason"].toString();` step, I naturally get the "Invalid attempt to read ..." error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the debugger to "verify that you have rows in a reader". Although `SqlDataReader` (and `DbDataReader` in general) implement `IEnumerable`, they are special because reader is the managed equivalent of a forward only read only db cursor, so when iterated, it really **consumes** the underlying cursor, or in simple words, it can be iterated **just once**. If you use the debugger, you are effectively shooting your single bullet.

Verify the buffered result instead (`reasonList` in your case).

**Update:** In fact in addition to above, you have a bug in your code - the `reasonList` array. In order to correct it, use something like this (note `new List<string>`, `reasonList.Add` and `reasonList.ToArray`):

```
public string[] getReasons(string Accession) {
    var reasonList = new List<string>();
    SqlParameter accNumber = new SqlParameter();
    accNumber.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
    accNumber.ParameterName = "@Accession";
    accNumber.Value = Accession;
    string selectText = "select reason from pendingList where accession = @Accession";
    SqlCommand selectStmt = new SqlCommand(selectText,toPending);
    selectStmt.Parameters.Add(accNumber);

    if (selectStmt.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) {
        selectStmt.Connection.Open();
    }
    SqlDataReader pendList = selectStmt.ExecuteReader();

    while (pendList.Read()) {
        reasonList.Add(pendList["reason"].toString());
    }

    pendList.Close();

    return reasonList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hm. So I need to Read(), and then what? Or am I completely misunderstanding you? (I feel like I'm just having one of these slow days today.)

Comment: @MattGutting You code is ok. Just don't use debugger to expand `pendList` Result View (as in the screenshot).

Comment: @MattGutting Oops, your code is **not** ok - see the update.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it in a minute.

Comment: Hm. Visual Studio complains for `reasonList.Add(pendList["reason"].toString());` - "object does not contain a definition for 'toString' ..." :-( `pendList.getString(0)` seems to work. Hooray! THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm a somewhat experienced programmer, just not in C#. I'll have to remember the List<something> bit.

Comment: @MattGutting Np, mate. Java I guess? C# is using Pascal case for methods, so either `pendList.GetString(0)` or `pendList[0].ToString()` should work. Take care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94027/discussion-between-matt-gutting-and-ivan-stoev).